# Ansible include_tasks giving syntax error

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-api

Ansible version: 2.9

**Play book**

```
---
- { include_tasks: test.yml }
```

**Error**

```
The error appears to have been in '/path/to/main.yml': line 34, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- { include_tasks: test.yml}
  ^ here
'}}
```

Fighting with this for few days! Please rescue.

Comment: => `- include_tasks: test.yml`

Comment: This also fails

Comment: probably, but I'm sure it is for an other reason now... that you have to fix. `yamllint` and `ansible-lint` can probably help you in this task. Reading the [ansible documentation as well](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted is not a playbook.  You need to list hosts and tasks:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: test.yml
```

Comment: If you absolutely wanted to use inline syntax (even if I wouldn't see why), you could use : `- {hosts: all, tasks: [{include_tasks: test.yml}]}`